# Universal deeplinks do not open the app the first time they are tried

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

When the app installs, I see a request to https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association, which gets a 200 response with the proper json response.

Odd thing 1: the app then goes on to try to request /apple-app-site-association which fails as the file not there in the root. Why would it fall-back to this file if it already has the .well-known one?

After the app finishes opening, I can go into Notes or something and click on a deeplink e.g. https://example.com/some/path, this will open in safari.

Odd thing 2: before the site opens in safari, there are several requests to both .well-known/apple-app-site-association and /apple-app-site-association. I am pretty sure that the .well-known request comes first, and there is one more to the .well-known version than the root one.

After that, I can now go back to Notes and click on the deeplink and it now will correctly open the app. All is right with the world.

Any ideas what could be wrong with the first .well-known responses that causes them to not work and to generate the fallback requests? Anyone else with this problem or any ideas?

Below is a redacted screenshot from Charles (app install finishes at 11:24:18), and a redacted response from .well-known/apple-app-site-association.

[image]

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Last-Modified: Tue, 06 Jun 2017 00:50:40 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "[redacted]"
Content-Length: 156
Connection: Keep-alive

{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "[redacted].com.[redacted]",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an error in the console when the failed requests happen: `6/6/17, 12:02:09 pm swcd(CoreUtils)[180]: ### Rejecting URL ‘https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association' for auth method ‘NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust’: -6754/0xFFFFE59E kAuthenticationErr` Which seems to point to a TLS error.

Comment: How did you see those request? In your mac? which app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue that you are encountering only because you are proxying the connection (using Charles Proxy - but any proxying would cause the issue). Apple is detecting that the connection was proxied and is not trusting the downloaded file.

In real-world scenarios you will not actually have this issue, as your users won't be using Charles Proxy.

Comment: This is exactly correct. And it makes perfect sense also. It is the SSL proxying specifically, just going through Charles is fine. The reason that I was proxying was to try to track down why it wasn't working - that must have been something else (possibly incorrect app id prefix) that has since been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

iOS scrapes both locations every time. I'm not sure if there is a defined order of preference if the two files don't match, but I know you run into strange behavior in that situation. Try to avoid it.

It appears you do indeed have some sort of configuration issue causing the file not to validate properly on the first attempt. Since you've redacted all the details that might let me look into that, unfortunately I can't be of much help there.

The re-scraping on link click after initial failure is new — I haven't seen this before. It must be a recent addition to help catch situations that would otherwise result in broken Universal Link behavior (network congestion during install, etc.). If you're able to debug your initial scrape error, this should stop occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The app prefix and bundle id are definitely correct, it does work eventually. The only other things I took out is the ETag and some cookies that just come from our site. What other info would you expect to see in the response? Also, I've looked at the ios console log from the startup (I'll add a comment to the quests) and it seems to point to a TLS setup problem on the server. The SSL cert checks out okay though...

Comment: This does sound like an issue that has nothing to do with universal links itself. Any particular reason why you are implementing this yourself instead of using a hosted deep link provider?

Comment: We want links to our site to open in our app.

Answer (score 0):

```
Why would it fall-back to this file if it already has the .well-known one?
```

Apple documentation suggests it will try the root folder on failure.

```
Handoff first searches for the file in the .well-known subdirectory (for example, https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association), falling back to the top-level domain if you don’t use the .well-known subdirectory.
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW10